# How can I repair leaks in an underground home's roof?

Tags: slab

I live in a 1400 sq ft underground home.  It was built in 1980's.  We have recently started to get leaks in ceiling slab.  Small but still leaks. The outside of the roof is 24 inches of dirt 2 inch Styrofoam the 8 inch slab. How do I go about fixing this from the inside or do I uncover the roof.  Then what do I do? Where do I get the product?

Comment: trying to patch from the inside will not work long term. taking the sod off and re coating the top surface would be the only way to have a lasting fix.

Comment: Can you identify the leak source for sure?.  Is there a Drop ceiling? Could the leak be from the cold joint at the wall edge, and running along the ceiling?

Comment: Are there visible cracks?  If so,  open them up a bit and try hydraulic cement.

Answer (score 1):

Uncovering it is the only way that will work. Given the expense and hassle involved, budget for a whole new waterproof membrane (EDPM rubber is one typical product - the expansion of "green roofs" in the past 30+ years means you'll find a bit more applicable knowledge and material than was around in the 1980's...) rather than trying to locate a leak. Root barriers are sometimes added as a separate layer to protect the actual membrane.

But...

This place claims to have a [leak detection/mapping system](http://leak-detection.com/products/) (electrical- based) that MIGHT let you actually find the leak (without digging first) and dig a smaller hole - I have no direct knowledge of it and remind you to treat all words from sales-people with due caution. But the principle seems legit.